# wp_query->set for several categories

Tags: wp-query, filters

```
$wp_query->set( 'cat', '1, 2, 3' )
```

forms sql query like

```
term_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

but I need

```
term_id = 1 AND term_id = 2 AND term_id = 3`
```

How to do it with `$wp_query->set()`?

Answer (score 5):

Try using [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):

```
$tax_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 3
    )
);
$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
```

Comment: Greate! Thank you for link. It forms query structure exatly I needed. By default it uses operator IN, but we can point AND or NOT_IN like this:

Comment: Doesn't this overwrite the current tax_query?